# php+ffmpeg add logo to video having error

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I create code for add logo to video using ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i a.jpg -filter_complex "overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h/2-overlay_h/2" outputvideo.mp4
```

When I use this code in windows dos there is no problem and logo is added, but it give me an error when I use this with PHP.

PHP:

```
<?php
    echo "Starting ffmpeg...\n\n";
    echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i a.jpg -filter_complex "overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h/2-overlay_h/2" outputvideo.mp4");
    echo "Done.\n";
?>
```

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'overlay' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\tts\2.php on line 3
```

How to solve this?

Please help me.

Comment: Escape `"` like `\"`.

Comment: dear sir i do not understaing,what to do??i am new bie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape `"` like `\"`.

```
echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i a.jpg -filter_complex \"overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h/2-overlay_h/2\" outputvideo.mp4");
```

Answer (score 0):

As Glavic has pointed out, you need to escape the double quotes in the string, so your command should look like this:

```
 echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i a.jpg -filter_complex \"overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h/2-overlay_h/2\" outputvideo.mp4");
```